# Delete all rows from all models except one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lately I have found myself doing this a lot in my Rails console:

```
Image.delete_all && Pencil.delete_all && Glass.delete_all && Price.delete_all
```

What is the proper way of doing this? Say I want to add a new model in that delete chain, it's kind of not comfy to have to retype this every time I want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can group functionality like this in a [custom rake task](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/custom-rake-task-in-rails/) or for simpler tasks such as yours you can put it in a utility library:

```
# lib/my_utils.rb
module Utils
  def self.delete_models(more_models = [])
    model_classes = [Image, Pencil, Glass, Price] | more_models

    model_classes.each do |klass|
      puts "Deleting all #{klass}"
      klass.delete_all
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your console just require and use it:

```
irb> require 'my_utils'
irb> Utils.delete_models # delete default models
irb> Utils.delete_models User # pass an extra model to delete
```

Anything else you might need to do repeatedly you can place in your Utils module and use it from the console.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a rake task that you can run from the command line

**lib/tasks/util.rake**

```
namespace :util do
  desc "Deletes records from common models"
  task delete_all: :environment do
    %w[Image Pencil Glass Price].map { |k| k.constantize.send(:delete_all) }
  end
end
```

You can create this rake task from the command line by running `rails g task util:delete_all`

Comment: I get this when trying to run it: "NameError: undefined local variable or method `delete_all' for main:Object"

Comment: Are you still having problems? I saw you marked this as the solution.

Comment: Yes. I still have those problems.

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?